# MySQLにあるJSONへの完全一致検索

Tags: mysql, sql, json

MySQL 5.7以降で次のようなテーブルJSONを入れています。

```
CREATE TABLE `p` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parameter` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `p` (`id`, `parameter`) VALUES (1,'[{\"a\": \"hoge\", \"parameter\": {\"m\": 4, \"i\": 5}, {\"a\": \"fuga\", \"parameter\": {\"apple\": \"red\"}}]');
```

ここで新規データが来たときに、parameterと完全一致で検索をしたいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？`JSON_CONTAINS`を使ってみたのですが、これは部分検索なので`[{\"a\": \"fuga\", \"parameter\": {\"apple\": \"red\"}}]`というデータが来た場合にも1がヒットしていまいます。しかし1がヒットしてほしいのは`[{\"a\": \"hoge\", \"parameter\": {\"m\": 4, \"i\": 5}, {\"a\": \"fuga\", \"parameter\": {\"apple\": \"red\"}}]`が来た場合のみです。

事前に`JSON_EXTRACT + CAST`での文字列検索も試したのですが、JSON_EXTRACTで取り出される配列はkeyの順番が壊れてしまい、上手くいきませんでした。

Comment: JSON型同士の`=`比較ではどうですか? `parameter = CAST('...JSONの中身...' AS JSON)`とか言う形で?

Comment: 無事に取得することが出来ました。お二人ともありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

まず、質問文の json は`}`が一つ足りないので、 json として不正な形式です。

それを直してテストを行ったところ、 OOPer さんのおっしゃっている通り、 json 型のデータを `=` で条件指定することで、以下のように、データを json 構造の比較で select することができました。

```
with entries(id, parameter) as (
  select 1, cast('[{"a": "hoge", "parameter": {"m": 4, "i": 5}}, {"a": "fuga", "parameter": {"apple": "red"}}]' as json)
)
select * from entries
  where parameter = cast('[{"a": "hoge", "parameter": {"i": 5, "m": 4}}, {"parameter": {"apple": "red"}, "a": "fuga"}]' as json)
\G
```

#### 出力

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
parameter: [{"a": "hoge", "parameter": {"i": 5, "m": 4}}, {"a": "fuga", "parameter": {"apple": "red"}}]
```